# did not switch on or die command in php

Tags: die

I have written these codes. But they did not work well. It hase some errors like this:

`Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\wamp\www...`

and sometime is shows `T_EXIT` error.
My problem is in "or die" command. Suppose it cannot connect to database. Then it should switch on "or die" & terminates the the program. But it didn't do that. How can I fix it?

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'table')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
```

Answer (score 0):

`My problem is in "or die" command. Suppose it cannot connect to database. Then it should switch on "or die" & terminates the the program.`

Answer comes Straight from [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '.mysqli_connect_error());
}
```